# Turn nested JSON data into HTML table?

Tags: javascript, json

I'm trying to use javascript to convert this JSON data into HTML table.

This is my code so far; however, I am confused about how to process the `'contacts'` part and put them into a cell like this: `first_name + last_name + position of the CEO and CTO`.

I was thinking of using `company_info[i]["contacts"].forEach(function(e){}` to extract the contacts data but I am not sure how to put it together in the cell.

Any help appreciated!

My code:

```js
function CreateTableFromJSON() {
  var company_info = [{
      "id": 1,
      "company_name": "ACompany",
      "established": 1999,
      "industry": "Tech",
      "contacts": [{
          "first_name": "AAFirst",
          "last_name": "AALast",
          "position": "CEO"
        },
        {
          "first_name": "ABFirst",
          "last_name": "ABLast",
          "position": "CTO"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "id": 2,
      "company_name": "BCompany",
      "established": 1998,
      "industry": "Med",
      "contacts": [{
          "first_name": "BAFirst",
          "last_name": "BALast",
          "position": "CEO"
        },
        {
          "first_name": "BBFirst",
          "last_name": "BBLast",
          "position": "CTO"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "id": 3,
      "company_name": "CCompany",
      "established": 1997,
      "industry": "Ivest",
      "contacts": [{
          "first_name": "CAFirst",
          "last_name": "CALast",
          "position": "CEO"
        },
        {
          "first_name": "CBFirst",
          "last_name": "CBLast",
          "position": "CTO"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "id": 4,
      "company_name": "DCompany",
      "established": 1996,
      "industry": "Tech",
      "contacts": [{
          "first_name": "DAFirst",
          "last_name": "DALast",
          "position": "CEO"
        },
        {
          "first_name": "DBFirst",
          "last_name": "DBLast",
          "position": "CTO"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "id": 5,
      "company_name": "ECompany",
      "established": 1995,
      "industry": "Med",
      "contacts": [{
          "first_name": "EAFirst",
          "last_name": "EALast",
          "position": "CEO"
        },
        {
          "first_name": "EBFirst",
          "last_name": "EBLast",
          "position": "CTO"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
  // EXTRACT VALUE FOR HTML HEADER. 
  // ('ID', 'Company Name', 'Established','Industry', 'Contacts')

  var col = [];

  for (var i = 0; i < company_info.length; i++) {
    for (var key in company_info[i]) {
      if (col.indexOf(key) === -1) {
        col.push(key);
      }
    }
  }
  //Create a table
  var table = document.createElement("table");
  //Create  table rows
  var tr = table.insertRow(-1);
  //Create table headers
  for (var i = 0; i < col.length; i++) {
    var th = document.createElement("th"); // TABLE HEADER.
    th.innerHTML = col[i];
    tr.appendChild(th);
  }

  //Add JSON data to table as rows
  for (var i = 0; i < company_info.length; i++) {
    tr = table.insertRow(-1);
    for (var j = 0; j < col.length; j++) {
      var tabCell = tr.insertCell(-1);
      tabCell.innerHTML = company_info[i][col[j]];

    }
  

}

var divContainer = document.getElementById("showData");
divContainer.innerHTML = "";
divContainer.appendChild(table);
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
    <title>Convert JSON Data to HTML Table</title>
    <style>
        table, th, td 
        {
            margin:10px 0;
            border:solid 1px #333;
            padding:2px 4px;
            font:15px Verdana;
        }
        th {
            font-weight:bold;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <input type="button" onclick="CreateTableFromJSON()" value="Create Table From JSON" />
    <div id="showData"></div>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: you only show one column for 'Contacts', yet you have two contacts in the data.  Seems to me you should have two columns "CEO" and "CTO", then in each, put the name.

Comment: I'm not sure if i should do that or do this: for example, firstname lastname - CEO, firstname lastname - CTO all in each cell

Comment: Until you know what it will look like on the end result, you can't really get much help (sort of like building a building - if you aren't sure if you want windows in it or not, how can your contractor know what to order.....

Answer (score 6):

As I understood, You want to put contacts array in the cell. We know that contacts column is `4` in nested for loop. You can write a simple if validation to check what the current `j` is. If `j` is not `4` which is `contacts` column, insert value in the table. If the current `j` value is `4`, then make one more nested for loop which will loop `contacts` array in each object.

```js
  var company_info = [{
      "id": 1,
      "company_name": "ACompany",
      "established": 1999,
      "industry": "Tech",
      "contacts": [{
        "first_name": "AAFirst",
        "last_name": "AALast",
        "position": "CEO"
      }, {
        "first_name": "ABFirst",
        "last_name": "ABLast",
        "position": "CTO"
      }]
    }, {
      "id": 2,
      "company_name": "BCompany",
      "established": 1998,
      "industry": "Med",
      "contacts": [{
        "first_name": "BAFirst",
        "last_name": "BALast",
        "position": "CEO"
      }, {
        "first_name": "BBFirst",
        "last_name": "BBLast",
        "position": "CTO"
      }]
    }, {
      "id": 3,
      "company_name": "CCompany",
      "established": 1997,
      "industry": "Ivest",
      "contacts": [{
        "first_name": "CAFirst",
        "last_name": "CALast",
        "position": "CEO"
      }, {
        "first_name": "CBFirst",
        "last_name": "CBLast",
        "position": "CTO"
      }]
    }, {
      "id": 4,
      "company_name": "DCompany",
      "established": 1996,
      "industry": "Tech",
      "contacts": [{
        "first_name": "DAFirst",
        "last_name": "DALast",
        "position": "CEO"
      }, {
        "first_name": "DBFirst",
        "last_name": "DBLast",
        "position": "CTO"
      }]
    }, {
      "id": 5,
      "company_name": "ECompany",
      "established": 1995,
      "industry": "Med",
      "contacts": [{
        "first_name": "EAFirst",
        "last_name": "EALast",
        "position": "CEO"
      }, {
        "first_name": "EBFirst",
        "last_name": "EBLast",
        "position": "CTO"
      }]
    }]
    // EXTRACT VALUE FOR HTML HEADER. 
    // ('ID', 'Company Name', 'Established','Industry', 'Contacts')

  var col = [];

  for (var i = 0; i < company_info.length; i++) {
    for (var key in company_info[i]) {
      if (col.indexOf(key) === -1) {
        col.push(key);
      }
    }
  }
  //Create a table
  var table = document.createElement("table");
  //Create  table rows
  var tr = table.insertRow(-1);
  //Create table headers
  for (var i = 0; i < col.length; i++) {
    var th = document.createElement("th"); // TABLE HEADER.
    th.innerHTML = col[i];
    tr.appendChild(th);
  }

  //Add JSON data to table as rows
  for (var i = 0; i < company_info.length; i++) {

    tr = table.insertRow(-1);

    for (var j = 0; j < col.length; j++) {
      var tabCell = tr.insertCell(-1);
      if (j !== 4) {
        tabCell.appendChild(document.createTextNode(company_info[i][col[j]]));
      } else {
        for (var x = 0; x < company_info[i].contacts.length; x++) {
          var firstName = company_info[i].contacts[x].first_name,
            lastName = company_info[i].contacts[x].last_name,
            position = company_info[i].contacts[x].position;

          tabCell.appendChild(document.createTextNode(" " + firstName + " " + lastName + ", " + position));
        }
      }
    }

  }


  var divContainer = document.getElementById("showData");
  divContainer.innerHTML = "";
  divContainer.appendChild(table);
```

```html
<div id="showData">

</div>
```

Let me know if this is what you want. If not, I will edit the answer.

Comment: That looks great! Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

I think the best approach is to add the contacts as `div`s or as `ul/li`s inside the contacts cell (in my approach down bellow, I used `div`s).

I also used array functions `forEach` to iterate the arrays, which can easily convert them to simple `for` loops if you want:

```js
function CreateTableFromJSON(array) {
  var table = document.createElement("table");                             // the table elements

  var col = Object.keys(array[0]);                                         // the columns names (I think taking the keys of the first object will suffice)
  
  // HEADER:
  var tr = table.insertRow(-1);                                            // the header row
  col.forEach(function(key) {                                              // for each key in col
    var th = document.createElement("th");                                 // create a header cell
    th.textContent = key;                                                  // use textContent instead of innerHTML (it's better)
    tr.appendChild(th);
  });

  // ROWS:
  array.forEach(function(obj) {                                            // for each object obj in company_info
    var tr = table.insertRow(-1);                                          // create a row for it
    col.forEach(function(key) {                                            // and for each key in col
      var tabCell = tr.insertCell(-1);                                     // create a cell
      if (Array.isArray(obj[key])) {                                       // if the current value is an array, then
        obj[key].forEach(function(contact) {                               // for each entry in that array
          var div = document.createElement("div");                         // create a div and fill it
          div.textContent = contact.first_name + " " + contact.last_name + ", " + contact.position;
          tabCell.appendChild(div);                                        // then add the div to the current cell
        });
      } else {                                                             // otherwise, if the value is not an array (it's a string)
        tabCell.textContent = obj[key];                                    // add it as text
      }
    });
  });

  var divContainer = document.getElementById("showData");
  divContainer.innerHTML = "";
  divContainer.appendChild(table);
}

var company_info = [{"id":1,"company_name":"ACompany","established":1999,"industry":"Tech","contacts":[{"first_name":"AAFirst","last_name":"AALast","position":"CEO"},{"first_name":"ABFirst","last_name":"ABLast","position":"CTO"}]},{"id":2,"company_name":"BCompany","established":1998,"industry":"Med","contacts":[{"first_name":"BAFirst","last_name":"BALast","position":"CEO"},{"first_name":"BBFirst","last_name":"BBLast","position":"CTO"}]},{"id":3,"company_name":"CCompany","established":1997,"industry":"Ivest","contacts":[{"first_name":"CAFirst","last_name":"CALast","position":"CEO"},{"first_name":"CBFirst","last_name":"CBLast","position":"CTO"}]},{"id":4,"company_name":"DCompany","established":1996,"industry":"Tech","contacts":[{"first_name":"DAFirst","last_name":"DALast","position":"CEO"},{"first_name":"DBFirst","last_name":"DBLast","position":"CTO"}]},{"id":5,"company_name":"ECompany","established":1995,"industry":"Med","contacts":[{"first_name":"EAFirst","last_name":"EALast","position":"CEO"},{"first_name":"EBFirst","last_name":"EBLast","position":"CTO"}]}];

CreateTableFromJSON(company_info);
```

```css
table { border-collapse: collapse; }
td, th { border: 1px solid black; }
tr { background: #ccc; }
tr:nth-child(odd) { background: #eee; }
td > div { white-space: pre; }
```

```html
<div id="showData"></div>
```

Comment: Thank you. I appreciate your detailed reply!!